# how to add a div before the ul tag

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, menu

I am using wordpress and i want to add two divs before the sub-menu part ul tag .My code is like this .

```
<ul class='main_ul'>
    <li>link 1</li>
    <li class='has_submenu'>link2</li>
    <ul>
        <li>link</li>
        <li>link</li>
    </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**i want like this**

```
<ul class='main_ul'>
    <li>link 1</li>
    <li class='has_submenu'>link2</li>
    <div class='scrol'>
        <div class='overview'>
            <ul>
                <li>link</li>
                <li>link</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

how this is possible with jQuery or wordpress??
thanx in advance

Comment: This is really easy, **you can't do that**, a DIV can not be a child of an UL, and neither can an UL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery `wrap` function:-

```
$(function(){
  $('.main_ul ul').wrap('<div class="overview"/>').wrap('<div class="scrol"/>');
});
```

or

```
$(function(){
     $('.main_ul ul').wrap('<div class="scrol"><div class="overview"></div></div>');
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/shE58/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Best way is **edit the template file**.

You can do this using `jQuery.wrap()` function:

```
$('ul.main_ul ul').wrap('<div class="scrol"><div class="overview"></div></div>');
```

take a look documentation: http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/2xvYJ/1/)**

jquery

```
$("ul.main_ul ul:eq(0)").wrap('<div class="scrol"><div class="overview"></div></div>');
```

This gets `ul` of index 0, then wraps it. It will help if you have multiple ul in your `.mail_ul`